# Store unknown size data to table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I realise there have been debates about this, although I can find a real definitive answer.

A lot of times, this question leads to a definition of what varchar(MAX) etc is, their actual limits, and what NOT to use.

What I want to find out is this:
I am giving the user an option to type/paste in whatever they want to in a text box, without limit.
This could be anything from a word, to a byte array dump of an image.

I need to then be able to quickly reference to this data at a later stage, using its TITLE or ID.

What would be the best way to go about storing this data into a DB? I have read that using varchar(MAX) stops indexing, and generally should not be used.

I'm not really well-off in SQL, so I imagine a possible solution would be to split this string into arrays of 4000, and store them like that.

Is this a good lead? Or am I missing something obvious?

General Model:

```
    public string a_Title { get; set; }

    public string a_Content { get; set; }

    public string a_AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
```

Where a_Content will be stored as the unknown.

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail about the db schema and queries that will be run against the data to allow for the best answer. Where have you read that using `MAX` "stops" indexing?

Comment: Have you considered serializing to a file and using the database to reference to storage point? Not saying it's the "best" method, but a possibility. It could serve to simplify things for you greatly.

Comment: `varchar(max)` is slower (on average) than a comparable `varchar(n)`, and an index in SQL Server can only hold up to a max. of **900 bytes** of data - so you cannot index a really large `varchar(n)` either.

Comment: @GrantThomas - wouldnt a `FILESTREAM` be better if you are going to go this route?

Comment: @GrantThomas that would require me creating a physical file every time a user saves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VarChar(MAX)` is intended for cases like yours.

Even if you chunk the data into `NVarChar(4000)` (or `VarChar(8000)`) byte segments to allow indexes to be built, what worth with those indexes really have?

You'll also be opening yourself up to the headache of figuring out where segments begin and end and then reconstituting them either in a nasty SQL statement or in some middle-tier client code.

Further, `VarChar(MAX)` and `NVarChar(MAX)` will be kept in-row when its possible to do so. That means until you are using `4001` or `8001` characters, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't have to worry about your storage type right now. You really have choice between varchar(n), varchar(max), nvarchar(n), nvarchar(max), even varbinary and text/ntext. All of them have its virtues and drawbacks. You can even chuck your blob-like strings into a file using FILESTREAM.

However, I believe you want to reference your data via some int or short varchar field, and you want to get your results relatively quick (not blazing-hot-get-me-data-yesterday-fast). There can be more or less optimal ways to do it, but don't think about that now.

I suggest this:

- create a table structure that satisfies your needs
- fill it with some dummy data
- implement data access using your favorite data access layer

When you feel happy enough, create a performance test wit, say, few thousands of accesses. This is the first time you want to optimize performance. Until then I would even forget the indexing itself.

*P.S. - don't split it to 4000-bytes chunks; this is a very awkward workaround and it can cause random search misses (not exactly random, you could find the bug after slow and painful debugging session)*

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build two tables, and leverage `VARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), Name VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE table1Text (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, data VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
```

and the `ID` in `table1Text` is a foreign key reference to `table1`. The benefit of this approach is that you can still index `table1` **and** you can provide full-text searching on `table1Text` without ever having any issues of each table affecting one another.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s, thanks a lot! I've modified the data type. I stand by the table structure because it allows for the remainder of my statement that you could provide indexing and full-text searching.

Comment: This can make sense, if you need to select the data from the *base* table a lot without need for the large text blob, or if you only have a large text blob for a relatively small percentage of your rows.

Comment: @marc_s, but doesn't the `VARCHAR(MAX)` data type dramatically affect indexing as well (i.e. even if you wanted to lookup the text, when the data reaches millions of rows there will be issues scaling).

Comment: What about 3NF though? :)

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, and how does this violate 3NF? I am not duplicating any data.

Comment: Would it not be okay to create 3 tables. Have the first one with the title, date created etc. Then, have a second table with `varchar(4000)`, and a third `varchar(MAX)`. Depending on the size of the text, It'll store in either of those tables?

Comment: @NewAmbition, that design will work of course, but it's probably a bit more overhead than what's needed right? I mean what is it you're going to do exactly with the table that has `VARCHAR(4000)` over the one with `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: Okay its more like 6NF (the join is unnecessary and thus reducible to one table), just nitpicking because I don't like 1-1 relationships like this.

Comment: @TheSolution Well, it could even be `varchar(500)`, I was just using an example. As I said, the person could put in one word, or a full on ByteArray of an image.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, if I didn't need to worry about indexing issues (i.e. a limitation in the engine itself) **and** the clear future need of full-text indexing, then I would make it one table.

Comment: @NewAmbition, if you're looking to be able to index that field when it's `<= 500`, then yes, but I would recommend just putting that field in `table1` and adding it to the covered index. If the field is `null` then you go to the big table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use varbinary(max) for this "catch-all" data column you're describing. The varbinary data type can store text (see below), byte arrays and entire files. The size limit is 2GB, but the nice things about varbinary (as opposed to deprecated image) is that you can return/download a portion of the data using a simple substring function. So, if you only wanted the first 100mb of some data, you'd used:

```
Declare @data as varbinary(100000000)
select @data = substring(DataColumn,0,100000000) from SomeDataTable where ID = 1
```

To insert text into varbinary you'd use:

```
declare @test table (
   data varbinary(max) not null,
   datatype varchar(10) not null
)

--insert varchar
insert into @test (data, datatype) 
values cast('Your Text Here' as varbinary(max)), 'varchar'

-- insert nvarchar
insert into @test (data, datatype) select cast(N'YourTextHere' as varbinary(max)), 'nvarchar'

-- see the results
select data, datatype from @test
select cast(data as varchar(max)) as data_to_varchar, datatype from @test
select cast(data as nvarchar(max)) as data_to_nvarchar, datatype from @test
```

Comment: Does this method reserve space in any way? I wouldnt want a simple sentence to use as much space as an image...

Comment: No, it's dynamic. A 10 byte sentence get's 10 bytes of space while a file get's what's needed up to 2 GB.

Comment: I'm not giving the user the option to save a compiled file, only text. I think varchar(MAX) would be better suited.

Comment: Understood ... I was responding to "byte array dump of an image" as one of the requirements. To me, that says you need space for binary data.

Comment: It will be a base64 string :) I'm sorry if I mislead you in any way :|